# Print multiple outputs for SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT count(*) FROM bossy.talent
where talent.date >= '2019/01/31' and talent.date <= '2019/02/28'
and (country_id = 1 or country_id = 2) and (current_status = 'completed' or current_status = 'incompleted');
```

This query print 2637 which is the total number of completed and incompleted columns. But I need separate outputs for completed and incompleted like

```
2600
37
```

2600 is the number for completed and 37 is the number for incompleted.

Comment: An alternative to group by since you don't seem to want to print the status is to UNION ALL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html where the first query part is for completed and the second query part is for incompleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT current_status, count(*) 
FROM bossy.talent
WHERE talent.date >= '2019/01/31' AND 
      talent.date <= '2019/02/28' AND 
      country_id IN (1,2) AND
      current_status IN ('completed', 'incompleted')
GROUP BY current_status;
```

You can use `IN` instead of `OR`s. If you want further bifurcation by country then add it also in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why should `GROUP BY` be used here?

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh Sharma. What if i want to print total count along with completed and incompleted.

Comment: @AkkireddyChalla, read about `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @Martin, `GROUP BY current_status` makes the query return one row for each distinct value of `current_status`. The COUNT(*) aggregation applies to each group of rows with the same value of `current_status`.

Comment: @BillKarwin ROLLUP is to add the outputs. But in this case I not only have completed and incompleted. My expected answer will be `completed 2600, incompleted 37, total 7530`. Total is the no of rows in the table.

Comment: Then see the answer from @VBoka

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by combination of `SUM` function with `CASE WHEN` clause.
For example, if we look at the completed, `CASE WHEN` will select 1 if current_status  = 'completed' and 0 if current_status is anything else. And at the end when you sum that you get a final desired result.(1 + 1 + 0 = 2 for my example).

```
SELECT sum(case when current_status = 'completed' then 1
           else 0
           end) completed,
       sum(case when current_status = 'incompleted' then 1
           else 0
           end) incompleted
FROM  talent
where date between '2019/01/31' and '2019/02/28'
and country_id in (1, 2);
```

Here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5f6b2cdb62919861a0008bc3b626217)

Here is how you can do it with UNION so you see one data under the other:

```
SELECT sum(case when current_status = 'completed' then 1
           else 0
           end) total_number
FROM  talent
where date between '2019/01/31' and  '2019/02/28'
and country_id in ( 1, 2) 
union
SELECT sum(case when current_status = 'incompleted' then 1
           else 0
           end) total_number
FROM  talent
where date between '2019/01/31' and  '2019/02/28'
and country_id in ( 1, 2) ;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3f4eb47d7562c7d6f8f19fa574b69fd6) for this second query.

Note that in this both query's you can use:

```
date between '2019/01/31' and '2019/02/28'
```

instead of :

```
talent.date >= '2019/01/31' and talent.date <= '2019/02/28'
```

and:

```
country_id in (1, 2)
```

instead of :

```
(country_id = 1 or country_id = 2)
```

Comment: Why would you do it like this?

Comment: OP's : "But I need separate outputs for completed and incompleted"

Comment: This produces 2 columns rather than the desired 2 rows.

Comment: @P.Salmon isn't that just an output/display issue?

Comment: @VBoka -- you didn't answer my question, I'm trying to get you to explain *why* your answer works, to make your answer better -- to show why this method is the correct one rather than using `UNION` or `GROUP BY` clauses. If you can **edit** your answer and add these details as to why, that would be a huge improvement. Thanks

Comment: @Martin Question has desired result in 2 rows and only mysql is tagged so no.

Comment: @P.Salmon here is the demo for one of the way'a of the correct presentation of data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a15335360027e6f5e6f93c9ed1d51924

Comment: @VBoka looks good to me just add to your answer so OP can choose.

Comment: @Martin did it, I added some explanation and the other query...Thanks!